# AS3 - Countdown Timer Bar - HowTo / Tutorial?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, countdown

I'm looking to create a 60 second countdown timer bar.  I've already got a text timer that counts back from 60, but I'd also like to have a visual green bar that reduces as time ticks down.  I'm including two graphics to show what I'm trying to create.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Whether it's some raw code to work with or an online tutorial, it would be tremendously helpful, as I'm a bit stuck on this part of my project.

Thank you kindly!

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 - Countdown timer color change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516267/as3-countdown-timer-color-change)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, it's a follow-up. The previous question was targeting the `TextField`, whereas this question is about the percentage bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516267/as3-countdown-timer-color-change/24517552), I'm using the code from that answer as a starting point:

```
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.None;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.Shape;

var nCount:Number = 12;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, nCount);
timer_txt.text = nCount.toString();
var totalBarWidth:Number = 500;

// this is the shape we will be updating as the timer counts down
var bar:Shape = new Shape();
addChild(bar);

// initialize the graphics of the bar
updateBar();

myTimer.start();
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
// add a complete listener to fade out the TextField
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, fadeOut);

function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    nCount--;
    if(nCount == 10) 
    {
        // if the count is at 10, switch the text color to red
        timer_txt.textColor = 0xFF0000;
    }
    updateBar(); // update the graphics of the bar
    timer_txt.text = nCount.toString();
}
function updateBar():void 
{
    bar.graphics.clear();
    // figure out if we're using a green or red fill based off of nCount
    bar.graphics.beginFill(nCount > 10 ? 0x00FF00 : 0xFF0000);
    /* draw the rectangle based off the ratio of nCount to the total
    repeatCount of the timer */
    bar.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, totalBarWidth * (nCount/myTimer.repeatCount), 20);
    bar.graphics.endFill();
}
function fadeOut(e:TimerEvent):void 
{
    // I prefer GreenSock for tweening, but this is how you'd do it with the buil-in Flash Tween
    var t:Tween = new Tween(timer_txt, "alpha", None.easeNone, 1, 0, .5, true);
}
```

Please note: there are many better ways of doing this. For example, I would probably draw the rectangle at full width, and then tween the `scaleX` property for a smoother look. This is just the a bare bones example to get you started.

Comment: another way is to use a mask and increase its size gradually

Answer (score 0):

```html
<center><object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="600" height="400" align="middle" id="Bleach-Vs-Naruto-V2-3"><param name="movie" value="http://www.qiqifiles.com/gahe/13/Bleach-Vs-Naruto-V2-3.swf"><param name="quality" value="high"><!--[if !IE]>--><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.qiqifiles.com/gahe/13/Bleach-Vs-Naruto-V2-3.swf" width="600" height="400"><param name="movie" value="http://www.qiqifiles.com/gahe/13/Bleach-Vs-Naruto-V2-3.swf"><param name="quality" value="high"><!--<![endif]--><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash Player"></a><!--[if !IE]>--></object><!--<![endif]--></object><br><a =>
```